# subir archivo a servidor y guardar ruta en BD con .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, formularios, webforms

Tengo un formulario web dentro del cual uno de sus campos la función es subir un archivo al servidor (ya tengo una carpeta donde se almacenan  los archivos) y la ruta guardarla en una BD. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que con tan solo el botón de enviar el formulario se pueda subir el archivo automáticamente y también guarde los datos del formulario?

Actualmente este procedimiento lo realizo por separado, es decir primero subo el archivo y después ya guardo los datos pero el usuario se puede confundir y no guarde(suba al servidor) el archivo y solo envíe los datos del formulario, es por ello que solo quiero tener el botón de enviar el formulario y ya se tendrían que realizar las dos funciones: 1. guardar los datos de los campos del formulario en la BD y 2. Subir el archivo al servidor

Como había dicho anteriormente tengo que subir primero el archivo y después guardar en la BD, y es así como lo hago:

```
<table width="682" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="rowData">
            <table border="0" width="75%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtIDAnuncio" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOpAnuncio" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Titulo del Anuncio:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitulo" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtTitulo" ErrorMessage="*Ingrese un titulo para el anuncio.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Cuerpo del Anuncio:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCuerpo" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ControlToValidate="txtCuerpo" ErrorMessage="*Ingrese el cuerpo del anuncio.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Archivo:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                        <hr />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" ForeColor="Green" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage1" ForeColor="Green" runat="server" />
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtArchivo" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Pagina principal:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkStatus" Checked="true" Text="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Inicio de vigencia:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFechai" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="txtFechai" ErrorMessage="*Seleccione la fecha inicial del anuncio.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="width: 126px">Fin de vigencia:
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFechaf" MaxLength="20" SkinID="txtGral" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ControlToValidate="txtFechaf" ErrorMessage="*Seleccione la fecha final del anuncio.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <hr />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="sErrors" DisplayMode="List" SkinID="vsGral" ShowSummary="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnAceptar" Text="Aceptar" CausesValidation="true" Width="100px" OnClick="BtnAceptar_Click" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnCancel" Text="Regresar" CausesValidation="false" Width="100px" OnClick="BtnCancel_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

codebehind

```
protected void BtnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        oAnuncios = new clAnunciosPortal();

        EntAnuncios = new EntidadAnunciosPortal();
        EntAnuncios.IDAnuncio = Convert.ToInt32(txtIDAnuncio.Text);
        EntAnuncios.IconoAnuncio = txtIcono.Text;
        EntAnuncios.TituloAnuncio = txtTitulo.Text;
        EntAnuncios.CuerpoAnuncio = txtCuerpo.Text;

        if (lblMessage.Text != "")
        {
            //EntAnuncios.UrlArchivo = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
            EntAnuncios.UrlArchivo = lblMessage.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            EntAnuncios.UrlArchivo = txtArchivo.Text;
        }

        EntAnuncios.PaginaPrincipalAnuncio = chkStatus.Checked;
        EntAnuncios.FechaDesdeAnnuncio = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechai.Text);
        EntAnuncios.FechaHastaAnuncio = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechaf.Text);
        EntAnuncios.IDUsuarioAltaAnuncio = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID_usuario"]);
        EntAnuncios.FechaAltaAnuncio = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        EntAnuncios.IDUsuarioModificaAnuncio = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID_usuario"]);

        switch (txtOpAnuncio.Text)
        {
            case "1":
                if (oAnuncios.InsertarAnuncio(EntAnuncios) > 0)
                {           
                    this.Confirmacion();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.AlertError("No se pudo agregar el registro.");
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;

        }

    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    { }
}

protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/AAA/BBB/CCC/");


    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {

        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }


    FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName));


    lblMessage.Text = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    lblMessage1.Text = " ha sido subido exitosamente.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas, el botón del componente upload y el botón del formulario hacen lo mismo, lanzan un evento Click que activa el envío del formulario **COMPLETO**, es decir, se mandan los datos del formulario incluido el componente FileUpload.
Por lo tanto ahora lo que estás haciendo son dos submit, uno al enviar el archivo y otro al envíar los datos y esto no es necesario.

En el evento Click en el codebehind puedes recoger el archivo enviado por el FileUpload. Simplemente prueba a poner el código del método UploadFile en el evento click y veras que todo funciona igual y tienes acceso al FileName.

Adicionalmente puedes comprobar si el archivo se ha subido con esta instrucción

```
if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
        {
            if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            }
            else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 kb!";
        }
        else
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: entonces el codigo de arriba lo coloco en el evento click del boton que envia el formulario?

Comment: si en el contenteLenght quiero que sea menor a 2mb serian 2048?

Comment: Si correcto, a los dos comentarios. Indica por favor si la respuesta es correcta y te ha servido mas que nada para ayudar a otros usuarios